# How to set working directory in quarto in vs code?

Tags: quarto

1. I am using quarto in vs code. I use Python in it.
2. In my .qmd file I don't know how to set a working directory.
3. I am facing a problem in that I have to write the full path of the data file while opening it.
4. I changed the directory by this

```
import os
os.chdir("/home/igb/Desktop/V_Semester/Part1")
```

5. I tried this.

```
file = open("/home/igb/Desktop/V_Semester/Part1/Gencode/bed_files/a1.bed")
```

It's working. Also, I have to type the full path of the file and vs code doesn't autocomplete the path so it's laborious.

6. I am expecting like

```
file = open("./Gencode/bed_files/a1.bed")
```